# Sucker punch running background jobs ActiveRecord Error - Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, background-process, mailer, sucker-punch

I'm trying to run a background mailer and depending on the params of the article, dump different users into the mailing list.  I'm getting this error upon request to make a new article:

```
Actor crashed!
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fca99f657c8>
```

Here is the logic:

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

  @all_users = []

  if @article.football == true 
    @all_users << User.where( :sport => "Football").all 

  elsif @article.basketball == true    
    @all_users << User.where("users.sport LIKE ?", "%Basketball%").all 

  elsif @article.volleyball == true 
    @all_users << User.where( :sport => "Volleyball").all 

  elsif @article.lacrosse == true 
    @all_users << User.where( :sport => "Lacrosse").all 

  else 
    @all_users = User.all
  end

    if @article.save


    @all_users.each do |user|
      ArticleMailer.new.async.article_confirmation(user,@article)

   end 
   redirect_to @article

    else
     render 'new'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit late to answer but this issue has no answers.

Your implementation of `@all_users` is an array of ActiveRecord_Relation objects except in your last `else` statement where you use correct assignation with `=`.

While you are iterating on `@all_users`, you actually are sending User collections to the job instead of single User records.

In your case: simply use the assignation operator `=` in all cases instead of the append operator `<<`. Keep your implementation of `each`, which will then iterate on records.